# inspect/debug js scripts loaded from a CDN

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools, cdn

In [medium](https://medium.com) website if I inspect the like button on any article, I am not able to view the js scripts. (I wanted to see the clickHandler's code.)

I have found later that the scripts are from another domain (CDN).

why can’t I inspect the js files if they are from another domain even if they are being executed?

I am using chrome by the way.

Take away (post discussion) :

- Events can bubble up from child to parent nodes.
- Event Handlers can be attached to parent node and can made to handled events bubbled up from child nodes.(Event Delegation)

Comment: All javascript files are maybe packed into a single one.
Some times, scripts are minified to gain space for the transfer.
In all cases, you have the script that is executed in your browser in local, so it is always possible to find which action is executed.

Answer (score 1):

You can totally inspect the click handler from a separate CDN. Thanks to the open nature of the web, DevTools has access to any JS that the page downloads and executes.

1. Go to **Sources** and enable [Event Listener Breakpoints](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript/breakpoints#event-listeners) for `click` events.

   [image: click event breakpoints]
2. Click the **Like** button on Medium. DevTools pauses on the event listener code.

   [image: paused on click event handler]
3. Click [**Format**](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript/reference#format) (near the bottom of the **Sources** panel) to make the minified file more readable.

Answer (score 0):

As presented [here](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/events) you should be able to inspect event handlers of DOM element using the chrome developer tools.
Most likely the Javascript code you will find is minified, which means it's barely readable. (But chrome also has [something for that](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript/reference#format), although you still have to deal with non-sense variable names etc.)

Comment: yes, but in case for the medium  articles, i am not finding any event handlers. pl check on the site once. thank you.

Comment: I can see some click event handlers, see [the screenshot](http://imgur.com/a/CwH43). I assume that heart icon is the like button (I'm not really familiar with medium). On the right in the event listener tab, you can see the click event handlers. When you click on them, it takes you to the JS source.

Comment: but none of the click handlers are attached to the vote/like btn right? then how come the ajax call is happening?

Comment: Yes, they are attached to it (or one of its parents), otherwise they wouldn't show up. It only shows the event handlers of the selected element (or its ancestors - note the checkbox).

Comment: Is it because all events were attached to document and then delegated to the respective "child" nodes? I was not familiar with the event delegation mechanism. I thought that events will be attached to the "child" nodes too.